# Unscoped enumerators within a class definition

Tags: c++, class, enums, nested

As known, static data members shall not be defined in the class definition:

`N4296:9.4.2/2 [class.static.data]`

> The declaration of a static data member in its class definition is not
>   a definition and may be of an incomplete type other than cv-qualified
>   void. The definition for a static data member shall appear in a
>   namespace scope enclosing the member’s class definition.

Consider the following class:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    enum E { x = 2, y = 3 }; //both enuerators are defined in the definition of `A`
};

int x = A::x; //looks like A::x is static data member, despite being defined in the scope of `A`

int main(){ std::cout << x << std::endl; }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/272832a1c4f5788e)**

In the example all the enumerators were declared within the class scope, actually:

`N4296::7.2/11 [dcl.enum]`

> Each enum-name and each unscoped enumerator is declared in the scope
>   that immediately contains the enum-specifier.

So, it's not clear unscoped enumerators are static or non-static data members. We can use them outside of an `object-expression`, therefore they should be static. On the other hand, we can't define static data members in a class scope. It looks a bit contradictory to me, couldn't you clarify that?

Comment: They're not data members.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Why?

Comment: A data member occupies storage, or is a reference. Enum value names don't occupy storage.

Comment: By the way, just for the record, even though nothing indicates any confusion about it (yet), the term "define" here does not mean "give a value", but means "give storage". So, a value can be defined in the class definition (if this member is of integral const type or is constexpr), but still that declaration is not a definition. It's just when storage is needed, e.g. due to taking its address, that a definition is required, then outside the class definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[class.mem]/p1:

> Members of a class are data members, member functions (9.3), nested
>   types, and enumerators.

Enumerators are not data members.

Answer (score 3):

In your example, `A::x` is not a data member at all.  It has no storage.  To prove this to yourself, try taking its address: you can't.